# Modify Style from GWT

Tags: gwt

I executed but only FF and chrome moves the textarea 0px from top and 0px from left but in IE
textarea is in default position.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyGWT implements EntryPoint {

   TextArea ta= TextArea.wrap(DOM.getElementById("t"));

   public void onModuleLoad() {

     ta.getElement().setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;");
   }

}
```

is there any bug or how can i change style attribute programmatically from GWT ??

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Don't set `style` via `setAttribute`. In JavaScript the style attribute is actually an array. Thus depending on how smart the browser is and understands you want to set the style attributes it will work by setting `style` or won't work.

You should set style attributes individually via `getElement().getStyle().setProperty()`. Or use the specific methods, like: `ta.getElement().getStyle().setPosition(Position.ABSOLUTE)` or via the setProperty method: `ta.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("position", "absolute")`. And the same for the 2 other properties. See the `Style` class for what specific methods are supported.

Comment: +1 Got this spot-on answer by asking Google: `gwt style attribute not set in ie` :)

Answer (score 3):

What about using style classes? I mean, you can write a style class like this:

```
.someClass {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
```

And then add the style class to the TextArea

```
ta.addStyleName("someClass");
```

It will help you to write a more concise code, without inline styling that could be difficult to maintain.

Comment: This is much neater, less verbose and extendible. Definitely the way to go

Comment: Pair this approach with CSSResource. Neat and clean.

You can then use ta.addStyleName(CssResource.INSTANCE.someClass());