# How to change font size in GXT Label

Tags: java, gxt

With GXT 3.0, I failed to change the font size of a simple label:

```
Label title = new Label("Hello world");

title.getElement().setAttribute("font-size", "50px");

RootPanel.get().add(title);
```

Don't find anything in the doc!

Comment: It's been a while since I've used GWT, but aren't the property names supposed to be in camelcase? In this case `fontSize` rather than `font-size`.

Comment: Oh, also - `font-size` isn't a DOM attribute name anyway. You need to change the style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify Style from GWT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082675/modify-style-from-gwt)

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is really late but there is a chance that someone else will have similar problem. So I found a solution like this:

```
title.setStyleAttribute("font-size", "30px");
```